# Change buttons on mouseover and mouseout?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouseover

I have created this but no idea why was the code cus it's not workin, Can anyone spot a mistake? I want to create a button, it's called **Calculator** and once the mouse over, the button will change to **Powered by X** and back to **Calculator** when mouseout.

```
$(this).fadeIn(change,100);
```

Comment: use  $('#calc_butt').html(change); instead of $(this).fadeIn(change,100);

Comment: Thanks @DhananjaySakhare..that works

Comment: @DhananjaySakhare but I got a small problem, it just turns to Powered by X, but the mouseout didn't work...

Comment: You got it @DhananjaySakhare?

Comment: Please see updated answer @Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$('#calc_butt').html(change);` instead of `$(this).fadeIn(change,100);`

**Edit**

I changed a method of doing it. Instead of using javascript i used css to achieve the desired output. Please let me know if it's helpful

```
<div id="toggleDiv">
<a href="xx" id="calculator">
 Calculator</h4>

<h4 id="poweredby">
Powered by!
</h4>

</a>

</div>


<style>
#poweredby{display:none}
div#toggleDiv h4#calculator {
display:inline;
}
div#toggleDiv:hover h4#calculator {
display:none;
}
div#toggleDiv h4#poweredby {
display:none;
}
div#toggleDiv:hover h4#poweredby {
display:inline;
}
</style>
```